# is it possible to use the layout files(xml) when creating fabric native module in React Native's new architecture?

Tags: react-native, kotlin, react-native-native-module

I'm trying to make a native module with new architecture in React Native.
but with layout xmls.
It worked fine to make native module without xmls when I followed the RN's official documents, but there's no reference with layout files.

> the code below is CenteredText.kt.

```
package com.rtncenteredtext;

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.TextView

import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

class CenteredText : ConstraintLayout {
  constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    configureComponent()
  }

  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
    configureComponent()
  }

  constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    configureComponent()
  }

  public fun init() : Unit {
    inflate(context, R.layout.activity_main, this)
  }

  private fun configureComponent() {
    
  }
}
```

> module tree

```
│  package.json
│  rtn-centered-text.podspec
│
├─android
│  │  build.gradle
│  │
│  └─src
│      └─main
│          ├─java
│          │  └─com
│          │      └─rtncenteredtext
│          │              CenteredText.kt
│          │              CenteredTextManager.kt
│          │              CenteredTextPackage.kt
│          │
│          └─res
│              └─layout
│                      acitivity_main.xml
│
├─ios
└─js
        RTNCenteredTextNativeComponent.ts
```

The main problem is that it's not able to find activity_main.xml and the build failed message is like below:

> e: file:///C:/steveloper/reactnative/test003/node_modules/rtn-centered-text/android/src/main/java/com/rtncenteredtext/CenteredText.kt:30:31 Unresolved reference: activity_main

is it possible to make a module with layout xmls?